How to install magento 2 using docker in window 11
Can anyone help me out with how to install Magento using docker step by step in Windows 11.
I was struggling with Magento installation.
Thank in advance

Please follow this link : https://ecommerce.folio3.com/blog/magento-2-docker-setup-guide/

To setup the env with warden docker:
if you don't already have a .env file, launch
warden env-init

here you'll be asked to provide environment name and select type (magento2)
else, if you already have the env file, launch
warden env up

you now have a running environment, proceed with magento installation by first entering in warden shell
warden shell

and then launching composer install and magento install command. I have a handy script to speed up this step. 
You can save it in your project folder and then launch it inside the shell
chmod +x magento-install-script.sh
./magento-install-script.sh

I'll paste its contents here:
set -e
## Install Application
bin/magento setup:install \
    --backend-frontname=backend \
    --amqp-host=rabbitmq \
    --amqp-port=5672 \
    --amqp-user=guest \
    --amqp-password=guest \
    --db-host=db \
    --db-name=magento \
    --db-user=magento \
    --db-password=magento \
#    --search-engine=elasticsearch7 \
#    --elasticsearch-host=elasticsearch \
#    --elasticsearch-port=9200 \
#    --elasticsearch-index-prefix=magento2 \
#    --elasticsearch-enable-auth=0 \
#    --elasticsearch-timeout=15 \
    --http-cache-hosts=varnish:80 \
    --session-save=redis \
    --session-save-redis-host=redis \
    --session-save-redis-port=6379 \
    --session-save-redis-db=2 \
    --session-save-redis-max-concurrency=20 \
    --cache-backend=redis \
    --cache-backend-redis-server=redis \
    --cache-backend-redis-db=0 \
    --cache-backend-redis-port=6379 \
    --page-cache=redis \
    --page-cache-redis-server=redis \
    --page-cache-redis-db=1 \
    --page-cache-redis-port=6379

## Configure Application
bin/magento config:set --lock-env web/unsecure/base_url \
    "https://${TRAEFIK_SUBDOMAIN}.${TRAEFIK_DOMAIN}/"

bin/magento config:set --lock-env web/secure/base_url \
    "https://${TRAEFIK_SUBDOMAIN}.${TRAEFIK_DOMAIN}/"

bin/magento config:set --lock-env web/secure/offloader_header X-Forwarded-Proto

#Only for magento 2.3.X
bin/magento config:set --lock-env catalog/search/engine elasticsearch7
bin/magento config:set --lock-env catalog/search/elasticsearch7_server_hostname elasticsearch
bin/magento config:set --lock-env catalog/search/elasticsearch7_server_port 9200
bin/magento config:set --lock-env catalog/search/elasticsearch7_index_prefix magento2
bin/magento config:set --lock-env catalog/search/elasticsearch7_enable_auth 0
bin/magento config:set --lock-env catalog/search/elasticsearch7_server_timeout 15

bin/magento config:set --lock-env web/secure/use_in_frontend 1
bin/magento config:set --lock-env web/secure/use_in_adminhtml 1
bin/magento config:set --lock-env web/seo/use_rewrites 1

bin/magento config:set --lock-env system/full_page_cache/caching_application 2
bin/magento config:set --lock-env system/full_page_cache/ttl 604800

bin/magento config:set --lock-env catalog/search/enable_eav_indexer 1

bin/magento config:set --lock-env dev/static/sign 0

bin/magento deploy:mode:set -s developer

bin/magento indexer:reindex
bin/magento cache:flush

echo "Magento is now avaiable at";
echo "https://${TRAEFIK_SUBDOMAIN}.${TRAEFIK_DOMAIN}/";


I would check out Mark Shust's docker-magento project on Git. https://github.com/markshust/docker-magento
